# Rails 3 app on jruby storing float in session looses decimal digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, floating-point, jrubyonrails

I have a rails 3 app running on jruby 1.6.2 on windows 7. When I do something like this: `session[:my_number] = 4.95` And then in another controller try to fetch the value with `puts "My number is #{session[:my_number]}` , the number is printed as 4.0, i.e. it seems to loose the precision. I have tried using both cookie store and db store. Also tried putting it in cache instead. To me it seems like a problem with base64 encoding, because manually encoding the number and then decoding it gives the same result. Any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using: [Number with Precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not a formatting issue. The number is fetched from the session as a float with the exact value of 4.0, so no formatting can get back those decimals. Using number_with_precision only gives me 4. The problem is the base64 encoding/decoding/marshaling process that is used to store data in sessions, regardless of the type of session store (cookie, activerecord etc.). Rails sessions use the platform specific `pack` method to convert the data into a base64-encoded string. In this case the jruby implementation of `pack`.